# How to Copy Full Div into another DIV with jquery in angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to copy whole DIV into another div.

```
   <div id="rightcolumn">

    some content

  </div>


  <div id="test">

  <div>

   <div (click)="addMatter()"> Add Matter </div>

On Component Side.

     $("#test").append($("#rightcolumn"));
```

But it's not working.

Is there any other way to do this task in Angular2 ?

Thanks in Advance.

---

Hello,

Now Copy is working but the problem is Dropdown do not have a any values. The drop down change event which created on main div also not working in this newly copied div.

Is there any setting for this ?

```
<div id="parentdiv" class="wrapper">
            <div id="leftcolumn">
              Filters:
            </div>
            <div id="rightcolumn" class="rightcolumn">

              <div   style="border:1px solid black;width:90%;">
                <div class="mainContainer">
                  <div class="rightSideContainer">
                    <select class="moduledropdownlistOption">
                      <option value="And"> And </option>
                      <option value="Or"> Or </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="mainContainer">
                <div class="rightSideContainer">
                  <span class="headerContainerForrightSide"> Group By: </span>
                    <select id="moduledropdownlist" class="moduledropdownlist test" (change)="OnSelectGroupBy($event.target.value)">
                        <option *ngFor="let field of fieldList" (click)="SelectedItem(field.ColumnName)" value= {{field.ColumnName}}>
                          {{field.DisplayColumnName}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mainContainer">
                  <div class="rightSideContainer">
                    <span class="headerContainerForrightSide"> Filter By: </span>
                      <select class="moduledropdownlist" style="margin-left:7px;">
                        <option value= "0"> -------- Select -------- </option>
                        <option *ngFor="let filtervalue of filterList" value= {{filtervalue.ColumnValue}}>{{filtervalue.ColumnValue}}
                         </option>
                      </select>
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div> 
              </div>
              </div> 

              <div id="childdiv" class="wrapper" style="margin-top:10px;">

              </div>
 <div (click)="addMatter()"></div>
```

in Component :-
export class SchedulerSearchComponent implements OnInit {

addMatter()
  {

```
 $("#childdiv").append($("#parentdiv").html());
```

}

In Above code drop down do not have a values as well as on new div no event is fire.

Answer (score 0):

Use clone method:

```js
$("#test").append($("#rightcolumn").clone());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rightcolumn">

some content
</div>

<div id="test">

</div>

<div (click)="addMatter()"> Add Matter </div>
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your response. Below code is work for me.  $("#childdiv").append($("#parentdiv").html()); The problem is DIV have a two drop down list. Drop Down List value comes empty. This two dropdown is like state-country. On selecting country state list comes. But after copy no event/value bind on new created dropdown. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: <div style="position:relative">
                <select class="moduledropdownlist" (change)="onSelectModule($event.target.value)">
                <option value="0"> -------Select-------- </option>
                <option *ngFor="let module of moduleList" value= {{module.ModuleTableName}}>
                  {{module.ModuleName}}
                </option>
                </select>
              </div>   This value not copy in new created drop down.. -- Select--- Worked after copy but ng for not working. any idea ?

Comment: Hello Marcos, thanks for interest. I have added code in main topic. sorry for by bad language and code. this is my first time posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need? Something like this?

```js
function CountryCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.countries = {
    'India': {
      'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
      'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
      'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
    },
    'USA': {
      'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
      'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
      'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
    },
    'Australia': {
      'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
      'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="CountryCntrl">
      <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
                    <option value=''>Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                States: <select id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
            </div>
            <div>
                City: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities || !states" ng-model="city"><option value=''>Select</option> <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value='{{city}}'>{{city}}</option></select>        
            </div>
        </div>
 
    </body>
</html>
```